# Enable 9p filesystem type in Centos 6 virtual guest?

Tags: linux, centos, kvm

My question is linked to this one :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880460/mounting-shared-folder-in-kvm-vm-error-mount-unknown-filesystem-type-9p

(but can't comment it)

I have apparently the same settings. Here is my problem :

I want to create a shared folder between host and guest using 9p virtio.
I'm following http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio :

```
# mount -t 9p [...]

mount: unknown filesystem type '9p'
```

According to http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup this line in my `/boot/confg-$(uname -r)` is not correct (and quite obviously) :

`

```
# egrep 'CONFIG_(NET_)?_9P' /boot/config-$(uname -r)

CONFIG_NET_9P=m 
CONFIG_NET_9P_VIRTIO=m
CONFIG_NET_9P_RDMA=m
# CONFIG_NET_9P_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_9P is not set      <------------
```

`

the doc tells me to enable it, ok, but how ? I'm not at ease with linux kernel settings...

at the beginning of the config file there is :

> automaticaly generated make config - do not modify

meaning I can't just add the line.

My questions :

Should I recompile the kernel with some option? 
Can't I simply enable that on boot, e.g. by changing something in grub settings ? 
Can I automaticaly enable that on CentOS installation ? (since this will be some kind of template that should be repeatedly done)

Comment: More generic howto: https://superuser.com/questions/628169/how-to-share-a-directory-with-the-host-without-networking-in-qemu/1301973#1301973

Answer (score 6):

CentOS / RHEL guys seem to have various reasons why they're not including 9p support.  Maybe because it was invented by IBM.  Here's how to do it:

http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=2858

9p is by far the fastest method I've found for sharing data with live guests.  If only Win7/8 had 9p support.  The SL tutorial is somewhat involved but well written, plus there are some follow-up posts that clarify a few gotchas.  I have it in action and it works well.

-Jeff

Answer (score 4):

Your kernel config shows you that you have 9P support compiled as a loadable kernel modules. Now you need to load these modules into your running kernel:

```
modprobe 9pnet
modprobe 9pnet_virtio
```

You can verify this with

```
lsmod | grep 9p
```

Try now your mount commands, etc.

If you want to have these modules loaded after reboot add them to  `/etc/modules.conf`. See `man modprobe.conf` for more info.

Comment: The kernel config explicitly says "CONFIG_9P is not set" there; which means that the 9P filesystem support is disabled in the build, and to enable it the reporter would really need to re-compile the kernel.