# How to mount host directory from Centos 7 guest in KVM on Fedora 30 host?

Tags: centos, fedora, mount, kvm, virt-manager

I am attempting to share a directory on my host to a guest.
Host: Fedora 30
Guest: Centos 7
Using Virt-manager I added a filesystem
Type: mount
Driver: Default
Mode: Mapped
Source Path: /KVMshare (SELinux context set to svirt_image_t) 
 
Target Path: /share

When I start the vm and attempt to mount using: `mount -t xfs -o trans=virtio /share /mnt/host` (/mnt/host is created) I get `mount: special device /share does not exist`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: https://cialu.net/qemu-kvm-on-ubuntu-and-sharing-files-between-host-and-guests/

Comment: @ajgringo619 same result. I did have to change the filesystem type from 9p to xfs, as my vm is xfs

Comment: When you attach to a shared directory - Samba, NFS, QEMU - the underlying filesystem is irrelevant. Since I have Windows VMs, I use Samba (never had much luck with this).

Comment: OK. But, if I try 9p, I get `unknown filesystem`

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112389/enable-9p-filesystem-type-in-centos-6-virtual-guest. If this still applies to CentOS 7, then I'd switch to Samba.

Comment: @ajgringo619 thanks for all the help. You pointed me in a direction that helped me find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

I set up the host as an NFS server, and the vm as an NSF client. I then could mount the host drive over NFS, like any network NSF share.